# How to extract PRINTED and HANDWRITTEN text from a scanned document

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is it possible to have cognitive services return both the PRINTED and HANDWRITTEN text from a scanned document. I can OCR the document and regardless of whether I have TextRecognictionMode.Printed and TextRecognitionMode.Handwritten I get similar responses, but I was expecting to have a Json file returned with a property for the TYPE of text read as Printed or Handwritten as I'd like to identify Handwritten text after certain Printed text.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the Product Manager for OCR at Microsoft.

This is currently not possible - as you noted, we have separate printed and handwriting OCR. That said, it is (firmly) on our roadmap - I cannot share the exact timeline, but we are working on it.

Please stay tuned.